# Delete button is not working in table

Tags: laravel-5.3

This is how my code looks like

```
   '<td class="text-center ">
     <form action="/patients/{{$patient->id}}" method="post" 
     class="delete_link">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    {{ method_field(\'DELETE\') }}
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm pullright">Delete</button>
    </form>
   </td>'
```

Remember my table is under single quotations. Someone help me to get this thing working, Please.!!

Comment: add your delete method in controller please

Comment: public function destroy($id)
    {
        $patient =Patient::findOrFail($id);
        $patient->delete();
        return redirect()->route('patients.index')
        ->with('success','Patient record deleted successfully');
    }

Comment: show your full table. is it a blade template??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
'<td class="text-center ">
   <form action="/patients/{{$patient->id}}" method="post" class="delete_link">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm pullright">Delete</button>
  </form>
</td>'
```

Comment: Just edited it a bit, and its working fine. Thank you very much.

Comment: Yes it is. Thank you again @Sohel0415

Comment: @R.Mseti glad it helps, make this answer  accepted as it may help others :)